# Page layout with resizable parts (with Jquery, Rails plugin or not)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, css

I use prototype since a long time, but for some reason I have to switch to Jquery.

I need to build a layout with resizable parts, I found http://layout.jquery-dev.net/

But I don't like the code generated, inline css is ugly.

Do you know any clean alternative? Jquery, Rails plugin or anything else

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about JavaScript adding the style attribute, then inline is the only way.

Otherwise you would need to set up a infinite number of classes with dimensions, and then change classes with JavaScript.

It is simpler by 10 fold to do this `style="left: 30px; top: 22px;"` etc

If you are talking about inline `<style>` tags, just copy + paste the text node into an external CSS file and then reference it in your `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the inline styles into a CSS stylesheet is what I'd do. :)